# Get cell height in javafx TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablerow, tablecell

I can"t find a way to programmatically get the size of a cell, kwowing the row and column indexes in a javafx.scene.control.TableView.

How can I find TableCell or TableColumn by  row and column  index?

I search a lot, but nothing found.

Thanks
Paolo

Comment: You can get the `TableColumn` by `table.getColumns().get(index)`. There is no way to get the `TableCell` by row and column index (a cell will not even have the same row index consistently anyway). Why do you need a cell's height? The table is going to manage the layout of the cells anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I know of getColumns() and I know how to find column width. I need celll"s height to find its center in an automatic test.

Comment: I guess one way would be to override the cell's `updateIndex(...)` method to set a style class (or CSS id) that used the index. Then use a lookup. (If you're using TestFX, the test framework does the lookup for you anyway.) You'd also need to make sure that there *is* a cell with the given row index, of course.

Comment: Also, typically in a test you would test your own code, not the library code. So it's now really clear why you would need this in a test... The bounds of a cell are part of the library implementation. E.g. if you were testing selection, you wouldn't test a click on the cell, you would select programmatically using the selection model, and then make sure your code responded appropriately.

Comment: I am using Froglogic Squish because of system test of  exernal brary

Comment: External library

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a clear way to do it, but for testing purposes, next should work:

- traverse Table's scenegraph
- note rows and columns on your way
- once you get to cell, you'll have row and column number
- determine if it's the cell you wanted and calculate its height

Traverse method:

```
// run it next way: traverse(table, -1, -1);

public void traverse(Node node, int row, int column) {
    //System.out.println(node.getClass()); // uncomment to see how traverse works

    // once we found a TableRow all children are from that row, so we save it's number
    int newRow = (node instanceof TableRow) ? ((TableRow) node).getIndex() : row;
    // same for the column, although there would be only one child
    int newColumn = (node instanceof TableCell) ? ((TableCell)node).getIndex() : column;
    // in my demo table cells are text, change to your implementation class for custom cells
    if (node.getClass().getName().contains("LabeledText")) {
        String text = ((com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText) node).getText();
        if (!text.isEmpty()) { // this check is just to filter empty rows
            System.out.println("### " + text);
            System.out.println("# Row: " + row + " Column: " + column);
            System.out.println("# Height: " + node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight());
        }
    }
    // traverse code
    if (node instanceof Parent) {
        Parent parent = (Parent) node;
        parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().forEach(n -> traverse(n, newRow, newColumn));
    }
}
```

Full sample: https://pastebin.com/A7cTvq4i

Comment: Thank you for your solution, soon as possible I'll apply It.